# Bounds of integration in terms of variable being integrated

Tags: integration, upper-lower-bounds

I missed this problem on a quiz and I'm not understanding how to it. The problem is: $$\int_{-3}^0\int_0^{\sqrt{9-x^2}} 2x^2 + 2y^2 \, dxdy$$

In his notes online, my professor says the way to solve this is too switch the order of $dx$ and $dy$, but can you simply switch the order of these without changing the value of the integral? He doesn't specify anything besides simply switching the order of $dx$ and $dy$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3533541/integral-notation-confusion-x-vs-t?noredirect=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has got to be a typo! You're absolutely right in being suspicious of the limits of integration for $x$ depending on the same $x$ — that doesn't really make sense. So either the original order of integration was $\int_{-3}^0\int_0^{\sqrt{9-x^2}} (2x^2 + 2y^2)\,\color{red}{dy\,dx}$ or that limit of integration was $\int_{-3}^0\int_0^{\sqrt{9-\color{red}{y}^2}} (2x^2 + 2y^2)\,dx\,dy$.

Also suspicious is the claim (from your professor?) that "the way to solve it is to switch the order of $dx$ and $dy$". You may be given an exercise to switch the order of integration, just for the sake of practicing that skill. But the new integral won't be any easier — so it's a fine exercise, but it's not the way to solve it. As others have already pointed out, the best way to evaluate this integral is by switching to polar coordinates.

**MORE TECHNICAL NOTE.** It's not completely true that the limits of integration for $x$ cannot depend on $x$, as I said above myself. We certainly can set up something like $\int_0^\color{red}{x} \color{blue}{x}\,d\color{blue}{x}$. But it's still true that *limits of integration for $x$ cannot depend on **the same** $x$*. You see, in this integral the red $\color{red}{x}$ and the blue $\color{blue}{x}$ are two different things! They unfortunately are denoted by the same letter, thus causing a clash of variables (very bad style!), but the context distinguishes them as two totally different things.

- The blue $\color{blue}{x}$ is the variable of integration. It's a bound variable, or a dummy variable in a sense, since the result won't depend on it. And in fact, any letter can be used as the variable of integration in the same integral without changing its value. For example: $\int_1^2 2x\,dx=\int_1^2 2y\,dy=\int_1^2 2p\,dp=3$.
- The red $\color{red}{x}$ is more like a parameter. It will be present in the result, because we will be substituting it for the (dummy) variable of integration. For example: $\int_1^x 2x\,dx=\int_1^x 2y\,dy=\int_1^x 2p\,dp=x^2-1$.

So technically speaking, the double integral given in your post is meaningful. But evaluating it would result in an answer that depends on that parameter $x$ from the upper limit of integration. And I seriously doubt your Calculus professor actually meant that.

Answer (score 0):

**hint**: Polar coordinates ! $x = r\cos t, y = r\sin t$. Can you figure out the rest....?

Comment: I realize the steps to solve the integral, but the variable being integrated in the first integral is in terms of the upper bounds. As I understand it, this integral isn't valid as is.

Comment: There is nothing wrong in having a variable in the limits.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add What @Deepsea has told, the polar coordinate version of the integral is

$$I = \int_{\pi/2}^{\pi} \int_{0}^{3} 2(r^3) dr d\theta$$

same thing as

$$I = \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \int_{0}^{3} 2(r^3) dr d\theta$$